# How to transition from Python/C to C++

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

I have programmed in Python for a year and in parallel started I have learned C 5 months ago. Now I am faced a need to learn C++. My knowledge at C ends with pointers. I noticed that C and C++ syntax is very common. So my question is: Do I need to learn C++ from the beginning ? or I can go straight to topics such: Pointers,Dynamic memory?

Also what level of knowledge do I need to start learning STL?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list

Comment: Going straight to pointers and dynamic memory will give you bad habits. [Read one of these.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: In fact that is exactly what you shouldn't go to when using C++, else you'll be programming in C in the name of C++. Know the difference! http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/c-vs-c++.html